# Spring Web Services 2.2.5 in Jboss 5.1.0 GA

Tags: java, jboss5.x, spring-ws

I'm having some problem while running a Spring WS quick start example in Jboss 5.1.GA.

When I'm trying to deploy a jar, with my web service, I get this error:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
Deployment "vfszip:/.../.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server/deploy/SpringWS.jar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Factory$org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor is already installed.
```

I'm using `Maven2` and these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I think, there is a conflict of jars in JBossand spring-boot-starter-ws's dependencies.

Can jboss 5.1 deploy spring WS projects? Can any body help me?

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: You'll need first to undeploy your `SpringWS.jar` from the server before deploying a new version of it.

Comment: @aribeiro Thank you for reply. But jboss didn't deploys SpringWs.jar. There are some libs like spring-core-3.0.6-release.jar or spring-aspects-3.0.6-release in JBossAS\server\default\deploy. But i use another spring's libs in web service.

Comment: Does your JBoss AS instance starts correctly without anything installed on it?

Comment: @aribeiro. Yes, I start Jboss correctly and to be sure now i downloaded Jboss 5.1  and tried on it -
 same error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Factory$org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor is already installed.
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:716)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
 at org.jboss.aop.asintegration.jboss5.AbstractAopMetaDataDeployer$MyBeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AbstractAopMetaDataDeployer.java:386)
 ... 40 more
'

Comment: @Vitaly, if you're installing your `SpringWS.jar` in `<jboss_install_dir>/server/default/deploy/`, then try cleaning your `tmp` folder under `<jboss_install_dir>/server/default/tmp` and restart the server.

Comment: @aribeiro. Thank you for reply. I have moved SoringWS.jar in tmp folder of default server and cleaned this jar in deploy and got same error

Comment: No, you misinterpreted me. You should've undeploy your JAR, then stop the server and remove your `<jboss_install_dir>/server/default/tmp` folder. Afterwards you should've restart you JBoss AS.

Comment: @aribeiro. Sorry for my English.
I think, I understand you, but it did not help. (I undeployed jar, stoped jboss and deploed in the deploy folder, and then restarted jboss).
Even when I use the Administration console to deploy, I get the same error. Also I made the try to deploy via Eclipse jboss plugin with same results. Thank for your help.

Comment: @Vitaly, give it a last try. Do what you've done already **but**, after stopping JBoss, delete the folder `<jboss_install_dir>/server/default/tmp`. Then, afterwards, restart JBoss and deploy your JAR.

Comment: @aribeiro Yes, I have tried to remove this directory. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @Vitaly, have you tried renaming your module? Instead of `SpringWS.jar` use something else? I was thinking that it may be a clash of names between your module and the Spring jars.

Comment: @aribeiro yes, i have tried.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? I have the same exact problem...